# how to make android app launch from long-pressing search button?

Tags: android, search, button, launch

I have been trying to enable my app to launch from long pressing the search button on the phone.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I would be very upset if I downloaded your app and it hijacked my search button.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've attempted

Comment: it cant hijack your search button because if multiple apps include this feature a dialog will show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this intent-filter on your Activity that you would like to show when the user long clicks the search button:

```
<activity...>
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```